# Is there a better way than passing /verbose to link.exe in order to see the effect of #pragma comment(lib, ...)?

Tags: visual-c++, linker, pragma

`#pragma comment(lib, ...)` can be quite useful to declare library dependencies (static *or* import) from within a translation unit. As far as I am aware the way `#pragma comment(lib, ...)` works is by transforming the library dependency into a `/defaultlib:...` internally (via the `.drectve` section of the COFF file). Being a default library, I think, affects search order and overall precedence, but the details don't appear to be well-documented (at least publicly).

However, there is one issue: one can seemingly only ever *observe its effect* but never see the real input order in which libraries and objects are passed under the hood.

While with `LOG_BUILD_COMMANDLINES` I can even see the effect of the usual environment variables (`LINK` etc.) on the respective command lines, the `#pragma comment(lib, ...)` seems to fly completely "under the radar" in that regard.

**Question:** is there a better way to see the actual effect on the input order to `link.exe` than passing it `/verbose` and trying to make sense of its output?

Comment: I think I may have uncovered a way via ETW, but some of the details are still finicky, so I need to figure those out before writing an answer.